# How to optimize a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

This is my procedure I think it is to long an not optimized. How can I optimize it better to short query?

This is the query:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FuncBusReport] 
    (@startdate DATETIME,
     @enddate DATETIME,
     @top INT,
     @state INT)
RETURNS @BusTable TABLE 
        (
            [Id] [int] identity(1, 1) NOT NULL,
            [state] [nvarchar](50),
            [Price] [nvarchar](50),
            [ReserveType] [nvarchar](50),
            [ObjectIdDepartue] [int],
            [IssueDate] [nvarchar](50),
            [BankId] [int],
            [Confirmed] [bit],
            [TrackingCode] [nvarchar](50),
            [Transactionsuccess] [nvarchar](50),
            [Name] [nvarchar](128),
            [TiketUrl] [nvarchar](128),
            [ObjectIdReturn] [int] NULL,
            [TelNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL
        )
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@state = 1)
        INSERT INTO @BusTable
            SELECT TOP (@top) 
                'ناموفق',
                [Price],
                'اتوبوس',
                [ObjectIdDepartue],
                [dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' ' + [dbo].[TimeOfDateTime](IssueDate),
                [BankId],
                [Confirmed],
                [TrackingCode],
                [Transactionsuccess],
                [dbo].[Profile].FirstName + ' ' + [dbo]. [Profile].LastName AS NAME,
                [dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4, [ObjectIdDepartue]),
                [ObjectIdReturn],
                [dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
            FROM 
                [dbo].[payments]
            INNER JOIN 
                [dbo].[Profile] ON [dbo].[Profile].[UserId] = [dbo].[payments].UserId
            WHERE 
                [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >= @startdate
                AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <= @enddate
                AND [dbo].[payments].ReserveType = 4
                AND [dbo].[payments].[transactionsuccess] IN (0, 1)
                AND [dbo].[payments].[state] IN (1, 2)
    ELSE IF (@state = 3)
        INSERT INTO @BusTable
        SELECT TOP (@top) 
            'پرداخت موفق رزرو ناموفق',
            [Price],
            'اتوبوس',
            [ObjectIdDepartue],
            [dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' ' + [dbo].[TimeOfDateTime](IssueDate),
            [BankId],
            [Confirmed],
            [TrackingCode],
            [Transactionsuccess],
            [dbo].[Profile].FirstName + ' ' + [dbo].[Profile].LastName AS NAME,
            [dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4, [ObjectIdDepartue]),
            [ObjectIdReturn],
            [dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
        FROM [dbo].[payments]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Profile] ON [dbo].[Profile].[UserId] = [dbo].[payments].UserId
        WHERE [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >= @startdate
            AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <= @enddate
            AND [dbo].[payments].ReserveType = 4
            AND [dbo].[payments].[state] IN (3, 5)
    ELSE IF (@state = 6)
        INSERT INTO @BusTable
        SELECT TOP (@top) 
            STATE,
            [Price],
            'اتوبوس',
            [ObjectIdDepartue],
            [dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' ' + [dbo].[TimeOfDateTime](IssueDate),
            [BankId],
            [Confirmed],
            [TrackingCode],
            [Transactionsuccess],
            [dbo].[Profile].FirstName + ' ' + [dbo].[Profile].LastName AS NAME,
            [dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4, [ObjectIdDepartue]),
            [ObjectIdReturn],
            [dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
        FROM [dbo].[payments]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Profile] ON [dbo].[Profile].[UserId] = [dbo].[payments].UserId
        WHERE [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >= @startdate
            AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <= @enddate
            AND [dbo].[payments].ReserveType = 4
            AND [dbo].[payments].[state] = 6
    ELSE IF (@state = 4)
        INSERT INTO @BusTable
        SELECT TOP (@top) 
            'برگشت خرید',
            [Price],
            'اتوبوس',
            [ObjectIdDepartue],
            [dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' ' + [dbo].[TimeOfDateTime](IssueDate),
            [BankId],
            [Confirmed],
            [TrackingCode],
            [Transactionsuccess],
            [dbo].[Profile].FirstName + ' ' + [dbo].[Profile].LastName AS NAME,
            [dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4, [ObjectIdDepartue]),
            [ObjectIdReturn],
            [dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
        FROM [dbo].[payments]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Profile] ON [dbo].[Profile].[UserId] = [dbo].[payments].UserId
        WHERE [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >= @startdate
            AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <= @enddate
            AND [dbo].[payments].ReserveType = 4
            AND [dbo].[payments].[state] = 4
    ELSE IF (@state = 0)
        INSERT INTO @BusTable
        SELECT TOP (@top) 
            CASE 
                WHEN [state] IN (1, 2)
                    THEN 'ناموفق'
                WHEN [state] IN (3, 5)
                    THEN 'پرداخت موفق و رزرو ناموفق'
                WHEN [state] = 4
                    THEN 'برگشت خرید'
                WHEN [state] = 6
                    THEN 'پرداخت موفق رزرو موفق'
                END,
            [Price],
            'اتوبوس',
            [ObjectIdDepartue],
            [dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' ' + [dbo].[TimeOfDateTime](IssueDate),
            [BankId],
            [Confirmed],
            [TrackingCode],
            [Transactionsuccess],
            [dbo].[Profile].FirstName + ' ' + [dbo].[Profile].LastName AS NAME,
            [dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4, [ObjectIdDepartue]),
            [ObjectIdReturn],
            [dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
        FROM [dbo].[payments]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Profile] ON [dbo].[Profile].[UserId] = [dbo].[payments].UserId
        WHERE [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >= @startdate
            AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <= @enddate
            AND [dbo].[payments].ReserveType = 4

    RETURN
END;
```

Comment: Look into parameter sniffing but before optimizing you might want to elaborate on what the problem is,explain plan,indexes etc.

Comment: I want to have short query with the same functionality

Comment: So what's preventing you from getting the short query? Except the fact that you would of course want someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Just a note, multi statement table valued functions and scalar functions can kill your performance, and you're using both of them here.

Comment: here i've used 5 if conditions so i want omite the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what i did here to shorten the query


`ALTER function [dbo].[FuncBusReport](@startdate datetime,@enddate datetime,@top int ,@state int) 
  returns @BusTable table 
(
       [Id][int] identity(1,1) not null
      ,[state]nvarchar
      ,[Price]nvarchar
      ,[ReserveType]nvarchar
      ,[ObjectIdDepartue][int]
      ,[IssueDate]nvarchar
      ,[BankId][int]
      ,[Confirmed][bit]
      ,[TrackingCode]nvarchar
      ,[Transactionsuccess]nvarchar
      ,[Name]nvarchar
      ,[TiketUrl]nvarchar
      ,[ObjectIdReturn]  [int] null
      ,[TelNumber]nvarchar null
)
as begin
  DECLARE @StateID      INT;
  DECLARE @StateTable     TABLE (col INT)
SELECT  @StateID=@state;`

IF   @StateID=  1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(1);
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(2);
END;
  IF   @StateID=  2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(3);
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(5);
END;
IF   @StateID=  3
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(4);
END;
IF   @StateID=  4 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @StateTable(col)VALUES(6);
END;
    insert into @BusTable
     select top (@top)
        case
          when [state] in(1,2) then 'ناموفق'
          when [state] in(3,5) then 'پرداخت موفق و رزرو ناموفق'
          when [state] = 4 then 'برگشت خرید'
          when [state] = 6 then 'پرداخت موفق رزرو موفق'
        end 
      ,[Price]
      ,'اتوبوس'
      ,[ObjectIdDepartue]
      ,[dbo].PersianDate(IssueDate) + ' '+ [dbo].TimeOfDateTime
      ,[BankId]
      ,[Confirmed]
      ,[TrackingCode]
      ,[Transactionsuccess]
      ,[dbo].[Profile].FirstName+' '+[dbo].[Profile].LastName as Name
      ,[dbo].GetUrlDownloads(4,[ObjectIdDepartue])
      ,[ObjectIdReturn]
      ,[dbo].[payments].[TelNumber]
     from [dbo].[payments]
       inner join [dbo].[Profile] on [dbo].[Profile].[UserId]=[dbo].[payments].UserId
      where 
       [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] >=@startdate
       AND [dbo].[Payments].[IssueDate] <=@enddate 
       and [dbo].[payments].ReserveType=4
       and [dbo].[payments].[transactionsuccess] in(0,1)
       and [dbo].[payments].[state] in (select*from @StateTable)
return
end;